# How to fetch object and its successor from database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

How to fetch object by some value and its successor depending on that value from database ?

To be more specific, I have table `articles` with columns `id`, `name`, `order`.
I want to fetch object with specific `order` and its successor in `order` value.
How should my query look like ?

**Example**

Data:

```
id name order
1   A   14
2   B   27
3   C   18
4   D   86
5   E   39
6   F    2
```

Queires:

```
FetchTwoByOrderASC(18) => (C,B) // 18 is C and the successor of 18 in this case is 28 which is B --> {(F,2)-(A,14)-(C,18)-(B,27)-(E,39)-(D,86)}
FetchTwoByOrderASC(39) => (E,D) // 39 is E and the successor of 39 in this case is 86 which is D --> {(F,2)-(A,14)-(C,18)-(B,27)-(E,39)-(D,86)}
FetchTwoByOrderASC(14) => (A,C) // 14 is A and the successor of 14 in this case is 18 which is C --> {(F,2)-(A,14)-(C,18)-(B,27)-(E,39)-(D,86)}
```

I use mysql database.

Comment: Tag the database you are using!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
Select name from table where order>=given_order order by order limit 2 #mysql
```

Or

```
 Select top (2) name from table where order>=given_order order by order #sqlserver
```

Comment: `limit` works on most of the db server if that's what you are worried for. But well tried ;)

Comment: `limit` doesn't work on most db server.  In fact, it only work on MySQL and probably Postgres.

Comment: Postgres also uses limit and it does not only limit to Mysql. but again good try